# CopyOnWriteArrayList(cowal)

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I understood this concept from some tutorial and as long as i know when one thread is iterating list ,other thread is allowed to modify underlying list and we wont get ConcurrentModificationException(CME) but in case of ArrayList we will get CME.

but in the following program there is only one thread(Main Thread) but still i m getting CME ..why?

is it because Iterator?

if i m replacing AL with COWAL than i don't get any Exception but i don't have the element "D" as well..why?

```
AL<String> l=new AL<>();
l.add("a");
l.add("b");
l.add("c");
Iterator<String> itr=l.iterator();
l.add("d");
while(itr.hasNext())
{
 String s=itr.next();
Sop(s);
}
```

Comment: i already did..."concurrent-collection"

Comment: Which, if you hover your mouse over it, explains that this is a .Net concept, not a JVM one. The reason you get the exception is because you are changing the collection (AL) after you have already obtained an iterator to it - it doesn't matter how many threads are involved here.

Comment: i changed the tag ..didnt notice as it shows .net concept..

Comment: thx but in case of COWAL it doesn't show the element "d" and exception ..here also the reason behind is am i obtaining an iterator first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `ConcurrentModificationException` because `ArrayList`'s iterator is **fail-fast** by design. Which means is that once the iterator is created, if the `ArrayList` is **modified(addition or removal of element)**, it will throw `ConcurrentModificationException`.

If you check the exception log statement, it is thrown at line `String s=itr.next();` by `itr.next()` method because `next()` method of iterator checks for modification by calling `checkForComodification()` method of size of `ArrayList` using `modCount` variable which it copies while creating iterator from list.

Now lets talk about the `CopyOnWriteArrayList` where you are not getting this exception is because `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is a **thread-safe varient** of `ArrayList` in which all mutative operations like add, remove, set are implemented by copying the internal array to new one and replace old array with newly created one.

So when you get iterator from list it holds a reference of array, and when you add an element to list, the list is having altogether new array. And iterator is still pointing the old array.

You might have noticed that the newly added element by statement `l.add("d");` is not printed on console. But if you print the whole list, it is there.

Here is your sample code with `CopyOnWriteArrayList`:

```
    List<String> l = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
    l.add("a");
    l.add("b");
    l.add("c");
    Iterator<String> itr = l.iterator();
    l.add("d");
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        String s = itr.next();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    System.out.println(l);
```

The output is produce is:

```
a
b
c
[a, b, c, d]
```

Hope this helps. 
Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

Error is because line

```
l.add("d");
```

you are modifying list structure (Adding or removing Element) after Iterator has been created.

when you are calling

```
itr.next();
```

Internally it is checking any structure changes in list (Addition or removal in ArrayList) and it founds that there is one element added and hence size of array list has changed.. That's why you are getting that Exception.

If you will add that element before creation of Iterator or after using iterator you'll not get this error..

below is the code of next() in ArrayList Class;

```
     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public E next() {
        checkForComodification();
       ......
        return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];
    }

    final void checkForComodification() {
        if (modCount != expectedModCount)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }
```